# DJango Jinja logic in HTML Page, cannot display html snippet

Tags: html, django, include, jinja2, code-snippets

I have the following code in an html page and am trying to use jinja logic to embed html somewhere specific (in the blog/about me section of the html)

**Code that doesn't work** (see specifics below)

```
<!-- About Section (Blog)-->
    <section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">Blog</h2>
        <hr class="star-light mb-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
            <p class="lead">This is the blog section</p>
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto">
            <p class="lead">The blogs outlined in the models section and stored in the database, are going to be displayed here.</p>

          </div>
```

It's these two lines that ordinarily produce an htmlsnippet output:

```
            {%block content%}
            {%endblock %}
```

In another place on the site (right at the bottom) I've used the same logic, and the snippet output has displayed fine.

**Code that works fine**

```
    <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
    <script src="/static/js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

  <div>
    {%block content%}
    {%endblock %}
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**The error I get is:**

```
'block' tag with name 'content' appears more than once
141           <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
142             <p class="lead">This is the blog section</p>
143             {%block content%}
144             {%endblock %}
145           </div>
146           <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto">
147             <p class="lead">The blogs outlined in the models section and stored in the database, are going to be displayed here.</p>
148             
149           </div>
150          <div>
151             {%block content%}
152             {%endblock %}
153         </div>
```

**Of course, I note the error** that says: 'block' tag with name 'content' appears more than once ...but my question is

1. Noting that I know how to fix the error (use the content just once), What is then the best way to include an html snippet, and more importantly, an html snippet that say, has posts, which are generated from the database? Is Jinja logic as shown below using block contents the only way, or is there a better way?

For instance, I have other html snippets in other apps in the same django project (e.g. in blog/templates/blog/post.html) ...this also extends the home page, but how do I include this in the home page? I don't quite understand the structure and how to reference things from different directories. Even if they have to be in the same directory, if you can only include one html snippet, how is it checking the folder it's referenced from?

**Structure:**

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django Tutorials\understanding_html_setup\pythonsite\mysite\aboutme\templates
This is where the header.html and home.html live (header is where the main bootstrap index page has been put for now)
there is another folder here called 'includes' which has all the html snippets such as 'mysnippet.html'.

**Important:** ** it is THIS 'aboutme.html' that is being referenced in the jinja logic above.** 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django Tutorials\understanding_html_setup\pythonsite\mysite\aboutme\templates\aboutme\includes\mysnippet.html

**Other apps such as blog:**

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django Tutorials\understanding_html_setup\pythonsite\mysite\blog\templates\blog
is where I have
blog.html and post.html

How would I include the content of post.html or blog.html in the above shown snippet (main homepage)

**Final note:**

The home.html page includes this code, which I note points to the inclusion of the aboutme code snippet. But still the question remains, how do I include other snippets, and what is  the best way to understand this structure and how things fit together. Tutorials or link references also welcome.

**home.html** (in: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django Tutorials\understanding_html_setup\pythonsite\mysite\aboutme\templates\aboutme\home.html)

```
{%extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content%}
<p>Welcome to this "about" page that is all about the website: </p>


{%include "aboutme/includes/mysnippet.html"%}

{% endblock %}
```

I think any guidance on the optimal and simplest set up will be invaluable for SO Django beginners. Are there flow or diagrams that show clearly how things ought to be arranged from an html and display point of view?

UPDATE:

Based on the answer below, I changed the 'content' name to something else, and it does indeed allow other snippets to be included. Thank you!

I still don't know a) the best way to organise html pages and to include snippets and also how to include a page that is drawing from a database: e.g. posts:

I tried this - that seeks to include post.html but it doesn't work - it instead just messes up the formatting and repeats the blog section elsewhere on the bootstrap page.

```
{%extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content%}
<p>Welcome to this "about" page that is all about the website:</p>


{%include "aboutme/includes/mysnippet.html"%}
{% endblock %}


{%block moose%}

<p>This is test text that says moose</p>
{%include "blog/post.html"%}


{% endblock %}
```

The 'moose' text does show up, but not the blogs/posts.

post.html (in the blog app) is:

```
{% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content %}
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <h6>on{{post.date}}</h6>
    {{post.body|safe|linebreaks}}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's telling you what is wrong. Why don't you just use another name?

Comment: Also note, this isn't Jinja, it's Django template language

Comment: Another name for what? The tutorial I followed stated that the use of %block contents% etc was Jinja! I assume you mean another name for 'content' (I didn't realise this could be done?). I am also asking about structure though. Including snippets in this way messes up the bootstrap output display ......is the only way or is there a better one!?!?